# Passing Variables to ORDER BY MySQL Statements

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to pass two variables into ORDER BY $variable1 $variable2 inside MySQL statement. The variables are gotten from a dropdown Menu form.

## **PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])){
         $sort1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sort']);
         $sort2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order']);
        }
        if(!@$_POST['order']){
            $sort1 = 'ID';
            $sort2 = 'DESC';
        }
        $topics = mysql_query(" SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title', 
                                       topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_owner AS 'CREATED BY', topic_date AS 'CREATED ON'
                                FROM   forum_topics 
                                ORDER BY '{$sort1}' '{$sort2}'  ") or die (mysql_error());
                        ?>
```

## **HTML FORM**

```
<ul class="sort">
        <li><form action="topics.php" method="post">
                <label class="label">Sort Table By</label>
                <select name="sort">
                    <option value ="">    </option>
                    <option value ="ID">ID</option>
                    <option value ="Title">Title</option>
                    <option value ="TAGS">TAGS</option>
                    <option value ="VIEWS">VIEWS</option>
                    <option value ="CREATED ON">CREATED ON</option>
                    <option value ="CREATED BY">CREATED BY</option>
                </select>

                <label class="label">Order By</label>

                <select name = "order" class="tap_Select">
                    <option value ="">    </option>
                    <option value ="ASC">Ascending</option>
                    <option value ="DESC">Descending</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" name="order" value="SORT" >
           </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Please help.

**UPDATE**

When I remove quotes around $sort1 and $sort2

I get this error:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SORT' at line 4`

**UPDATE 2**

When I did the $sql = "....." , without passing it through mysql_querry()
I got this

`SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title', topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_owner AS 'CREATED BY', topic_date AS 'CREATED ON' FROM forum_topics ORDER BY ID SORT`

Comment: You have two elements called 'order' in your HTML form, the select and the submit button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use quotes, e.g.

```
ORDER BY 'ID' 'DESC'
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

the quotes turn id and desc into plain strings, not keywords/fieldnames.

Comment: @dot: build your query as `$sql = "...."`, so you can echo out the string you're building. This is always a good idea, especially when you're debugging - far easier to see the "real" query, rather than just the snippet you get from the error messages. So... $sql, then show us the query you're building.

Comment: @DotOyes - your submit button is called `order` - you're picking up the value of that instead of the select that has the same name.

Comment: `ORDER BY ID SORT` is wrong. as andrewsi says, your submit button has the same `name=` as your sort-by `<select>`, and the submit button's value is overwriting the select.

Comment: Also note that the column names contain spaces, so backticks are required.

Comment: @andrewsi , I changed the name of submit button to something else, but still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

remove the brackets and add a comma between the sort elements

```
ORDER BY $sort1 $sort2  ") or die (
```

edit:  make the following changes so we can see what is going on...

take this line(s)

```
$topics = mysql_query(" SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title',  
                                   topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_owner AS 'CREATED BY', topic_date AS 'CREATED ON' 
                            FROM   forum_topics  
                            ORDER BY '{$sort1}' '{$sort2}'  ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Stick the query into a variable, and replace the stringin the mysql_query with the variable;

```
$query="SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title',  
                                   topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_owner AS 'CREATED BY', topic_date AS 'CREATED ON' 
                            FROM   forum_topics  
                            ORDER BY '{$sort1}' '{$sort2}'  ";
$topics = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

then echo the query and cut/paste the results to the question.  Something isn't happening the way you think it is.

```
echo $query;
```

Comment: removed the quotes and comma...  misread your use of two "sort" variables as being seperate sortby columns vs a "sortby" and "direction"

Comment: see updated response... note I left your version of the query intact in my example

Answer (score 1):

It seems your column names contain spaces, so you need to use backticks:

```
ORDER BY `{$sort1}` {$sort2}
```

Also note that `mysql_real_escape_string` does not offer any protection in case of the `ORDER BY` clause. You need to check your input against a whitelist of allowed inputs.

Comment: If I'm getting the values from a dropdown menu, does this help as a whitelist ? What do you regard as a whitelist ?

Comment: @Dot Oyes No, never trust user input. You would need to hard-code a list of column names (and asc / desc order...) and check against that. Anybody can post any value to your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$topics = mysql_query("SELECT
    topic_id AS `ID`,
    topic_head AS `Title`, 
    topic_tags AS `TAGS`,
    topic_owner AS `CREATED BY`,
    topic_date AS `CREATED ON`
FROM   forum_topics 
ORDER BY {$sort1} {$sort2}'
") or die (mysql_error());
```

You need to remove `'` around ORDER BY values. Also please note the preferred used of back-ticks around alias values.

Note also that you should use mysqli_* or PDO as mysql_* are deprecated (See big red warnings on PHP.net throughout most mysql_* related functionality.

Comment: @DotOyes if that error is still showing `near 'SORT'` that would seem to indicate that you are still sending the single quotes.

Comment: your oder-by is incorrect.  OP wants to specify both the field and sort direction. You're changing to using two fields instead.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, in looking more closely at the form, I think you are right. I will adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax is working for me in PHP 7.4.12 and MySQL 5.7.32:

```
$sort = sanitize_text_field($_POST['sort']; // e.g., 'title'
$order = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order']; // e.g., 'ASC'
$order_by = $sort . ' ' . $order;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        MyTable
    ORDER BY
        $order_by
" );
```